# Postgresql - Problem when update table with temporary table "You might need to add explicit type casts"

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm in the middle of developing an app using node.js. my database is PostgreSQL. I tried to create a temporary table and then update my main table with that temporary table. the reason is that i have many records and data that must update every second. i know that one of the must efficient way is that first create a temp table by your data and then update main table with temporary table.
i create temp table successfully but when i try to update my main table i catch "`No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`" error.
anybody can help me or hint me how i can solve this problem?
my temporary creation sql is :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_binance_tradika_signals
  (id, thpars_dati, thpars_vise, thpars_aipi, thpars_code, thpars_site, thpars_owne, thpars_list, thpars_prio, signal_state, signal_date, signal_account, signal_exchange, signal_abbrev, signal_id, signal_uid, signal_andis, signal_coin, signal_base, signal_symbol, signal_side, signal_step_log, signal_step_update, signal_lotstep, signal_lotint_step, signal_pricetick, signal_priceint_tick, signal_time_init, signal_date_alive, signal_dca_buy, signal_dca_sell, signal_amount_type, signal_score, open_percent, open_price, open_amount, open_date, open_trigger, open_prv_abbrev, open_prv_title, open_prv_code, close_percent, close_price, close_amount, close_date, close_trigger, close_period, close_result, close_prv_abbrev, close_prv_title, close_prv_code, price_latest_percent, price_latest_price, price_higest_percent, price_higest_price, price_lowest_percent, price_lowest_price, point_buy_percent, point_buy_price, point_buy_amount, point_buy_date, point_buy_lifelong, point_buy_lifetime, point_buy_bool, point_sell_percent, point_sell_price, point_sell_amount, point_sell_date, point_sell_lifelong, point_sell_lifetime, point_sell_bool, point_place_percent, point_place_price, point_eject_percent, point_eject_price, point_stoploss_percent, point_stoploss_price, point_stoploss_bool, point_expire_percent, point_expire_price, point_expire_bool, point_expire_date, point_expire_duration) AS
VALUES
('100100104895', '2021-07-08 22:59:15', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 'ALIVE', '2021-07-08 22:59:08', 'Tradika.net', 'Binance', 'SL', 'JIMP_20210708225908_KEYUSDT', 'JIMP_20210708225908_KEYUSDT_SL', 'KEYUSDT_SL', 'KEY', 'USDT', 'KEYUSDT', 'Buy', 0.5, 0.1, 1, 0, 0.000001, 6, 60, '2021-07-08 23:00:15', 0.6, 0.6, null, 1, 0, 0.007369, null, '2021-07-08 22:59:15', 'SIGNAL', 'JIMP', 'Jim Panda Signals', 441, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0.007369, 0, 0.007369, 0, 0.007369, -2.5, 0.007185, '1795', null, 600, null, null, -1, 0.007296, null, null, 43200, null, null, -2.3, 0.0072, -2.1, 0.007215, -6, 0.006927, null, 0.25, 0.007388, null, null, 345600),

('100100104896', '2021-07-08 22:59:15', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 'ALIVE', '2021-07-08 22:59:08', 'Parsika.net', 'Binance', 'MP', 'JIMP_20210708225908_KEYUSDT', 'JIMP_20210708225908_KEYUSDT_MP', 'KEYUSDT_MP', 'KEY', 'USDT', 'KEYUSDT', 'Buy', 1, 0.2, 1, 0, 0.000001, 6, 100, '2021-07-08 23:00:55', 1, 1, null, 1, 0, 0.007369, null, '2021-07-08 22:59:15', 'SIGNAL', 'JIMP', 'Jim Panda Signals', 441, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0.007369, 0, 0.007369, 0, 0.007369, -10, 0.006633, '1944', null, 600, null, null, -4, 0.007075, null, null, 86400, null, null, -9, 0.006706, -8.5, 0.006743, -15, 0.006264, null, 0.25, 0.007388, null, null, 345600)
;
```

and my update SQL from temporary table is :

```
UPDATE binance_tradika_signals
SET 
signal_state = t.signal_state,
price_latest_price = t.price_latest_price
FROM temp_binance_tradika_signals t
WHERE t.id = binance_tradika_signals.id;
```

any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why is `id` a String? If that is a number it should be provided as one. And `thpars_dati` looks like a timestamp so the value should be provided as a proper timestamp value: `timestamp '2021-07-08 22:59:15'` And why do you include so many unnecessary columns in the temp table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, ......  i provide id as int and the problem gone away .... Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, `'2021-07-08 22:59:15'` is acceptable as a value for timestamp. It will be implicitly cast on entry as long as it is a properly formatted timestamp string.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I mentioned that, so that the temp table is already created with the correct data types. I try to avoid implicit type conversion wherever I can because it simply contains too many hidden pitfalls.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  : do you guys have a better solution with higher performance to do this scenario?

Comment: Not sure it would need more information; 1) In the example you are only updating two fields, yet you create the temp table with many fields. Is that necessary? 2) How many records are you importing on each iteration? Add answers to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, 1) in each update i probably do update 100 fields per records. 2)my app maybe update more than 10,000 to 20,000 records update per each 2 seconds. 3) i add answer to my question after i get the final solution for the main problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

1. `id` must present as integer not string.
2. the first row data of insert into temp table specify the datatype. so for example if you insert `signal_step_log` into temp table as JSON datatype, if you define this row as Varchar, int, Bool etc .... you will get an error.

Hope this will be useful.